# split and arrange string column data

Tags: r

New to R, so I'm a bit lost.
I have a data set with various variables including the following column "drink_daily":

```
drink_daily <- c("(ID 3) Cola & (ID 1) Sprite",
  "(ID 1) Sprite & (ID 3) Cola",
  "(ID 2) water & (ID 3) Cola & (ID 4) Other",
  "(ID 3) Cola & (ID 1) Sprite & (ID 2) water")
```

etc.

I need to end up with something like this in the dataframe:

```
[1] "1" & "3"
[2] "1" & "3"
[3] "2" & "3" & "4"
[4] "1" & "2" & "3"
```

- a) I would like to arrange for all the string to be in alphabetical (1-4) order
- b) split the strings within the column to 4 variables
- c) re code to text to numbers (1->4)
- d) merger the 4 columns back into one

Comment: Do you mean one number for each column or turn it into a string `"1 & 3"`? `&` without quotes means something else in R.

Comment: I would like to get "1 and 3" as the answer, but be able to later put 1 or 3 in frequency tables, so I would need them as separte variables in one string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with something which is not very pretty - partly because R may not be the best tool to do this with - but it does the trick.

Here, strsplit is used to break up the blocks separated by '&'.
gsub strips the brackets and 'ID'.
as.numeric turns it into numbers (alternative: as.integer).
sort does not need further explanation

The result is a list of vectors with all IDs sorted. Names of list items are the original items

```
df <- c("(ID 3) Cola & (ID 1) Sprite",
        "(ID 1) Sprite & (ID 3) Cola",
        "(ID 2) water & (ID 3) Cola & (ID 4) Other",
        "(ID 3) Cola & (ID 1) Sprite & (ID 2) water")

df2 <- sapply(df,function(x) strsplit(x,split='& *'))

result <- lapply(df2, function(x) {
    sort(as.numeric(gsub(').*','',gsub('\\(ID ','',x))))
})


## Show result:
result
 $`(ID 3) Cola & (ID 1) Sprite`
[1] 1 3

 $`(ID 1) Sprite & (ID 3) Cola`
[1] 1 3

 $`(ID 2) water & (ID 3) Cola & (ID 4) Other`
[1] 2 3 4

 $`(ID 3) Cola & (ID 1) Sprite & (ID 2) water`
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get some help from the `stringr` and `purrr` libraries. For example

```
library(purrr)
stringr::str_match_all(drink_daily, "\\(ID (\\d+)\\)") %>% 
  map(function(x) x[,2]) %>% 
  map(as.numeric) %>% 
  map(sort) %>% 
  map_chr(paste, collapse=" & ")
# [1] "1 & 3"     "1 & 3"     "2 & 3 & 4" "1 & 2 & 3"
```

We use `str_match_all` to extract the number inside the string "(ID #)" and then sort those and paste them back together.

Answer (score 1):

Justo to introduce `stringi` package which makes dealing with strings a bit easier (although same structure as @Mr.Flick's answer),

```
library(stringi)

sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(drink_daily, '\\d+'), function(i) 
                                              paste(sort(as.numeric(i)), collapse = ' & '))

#[1] "1 & 3"     "1 & 3"     "2 & 3 & 4" "1 & 2 & 3"
```